# how rails around_action works with return statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to the ruby and RoR world and I have recently learned about blocks.
I have read that return inside block actually returns from the top most function that called it

for example

```
def test 
    value = yield
    puts value

end

# prints "return inside block"
test do
      "return inside block"
end

# prints nothing
test do
      return "return inside block"
end
```

so if this is how blocks and "return" works in ruby, how come around_action don't behave the same?

for example

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
    around_action :aroundy
    def test
        render json: {amit:"hello"} 
        puts "hello"
        return
    end
    
    # prints after even though the action "test" calls return
    def aroundy
        puts "before"
        yield  
        puts "after"
    end
end
```

How is it possible that the code continues to run after the yield if I called return inside the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a big difference between these two situations: your action `test` is a method, not a block. This alone is enough to throw out all expectations that `return` should behave the same way as it does in blocks.

In addition, the way it's called is not as simple as in your first snippet. [Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/533c5c3a532a01ca5ae6ddd3f04137b13e9271ab/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L199-L203)'s how `around_action` is implemented in rails, for example:

```
define_method "#{callback}_action" do |*names, &blk|
  _insert_callbacks(names, blk) do |name, options|
    set_callback(:process_action, callback, name, options)
  end
end
```

Comment: Also that return in the action is useless/redundant, but it does not matter in this case.